# Mapping Cloud Providers resources/modules etc. used by Terraform

Tags: terraform

I started learning Terraform through AWS since this is the most popular Cloud Provider currently. However, I am thinking about GCP now, and the first thing that I see there is no simple mapping between those vendors (others as well I suppose). Let's say we are creating a user with `aws_iam_user` resource in AWS, but unfortunately, there is no simple correlation like removing `aws` prefix with `google`. I know we are not living in an ideal world :) but it would be great just to manipulate those prefixes.

So my question to more experienced guys is how you handle that if you want to create similar block of code for GCP based on previously created for AWS in Terraform? Is there some tool where let's say I put `aws_iam_user` resource and get equivalent for Azure, GCP and others?

Comment: I started thinking if there is some bot installed over here. This is my third post in the last two/three days each of them got after several minutes `-1`.
StackOverflow admins, please take a look at that.

Comment: I don't think the `-1` is a bot because this question is pretty generalized & stack overflow is about being more direct, sharing an actual problem you faced so that you can get a proper answer. It's not supposed to be for generalized discussions. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/tour Granted, I'm not an admin but I'm not surprised to see a `-1` on this question.

Comment: I have faced with problem translating `aws_iam_user`resource from AWS to GCP in my Terraform file, That is why I asked about the tool that might be used to map resources/modules from different Cloud Providers (2nd question from the above post), and different approaches to solve that (1st question). So I am very surprised to see `-1`.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a tool that translates infra from one public cloud to another. You need to reference docs and learn each cloud. It isn't a difference of just naming. This is why people often specialize in a single cloud, and also why businesses going multi-cloud is incredibly expensive in both time and money.